# Specifying a request body doing a Gatling POST

Tags: performance, gatling

I'm a fresh newbie to Gatling.  I'm trying to send a POST message to an HTTP API using Gatling.  I tried the following:

```
package app.basic
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class basicPost extends Simulation {
  val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""")
  object Post {
      // repeat is a loop resolved at RUNTIME
      val post = repeat(50) { 
      exec(http("Post Data")
          .post("/data")
          .queryParam("""size""", "10"))
          .headers(headers_10)
          .body("""{"id1":"0000000000"}""")
          .pause(1)
  }
  }
  val httpConf = http.baseURL("http://amazonperf-env.elasticbeanstalk.com")   
  val users = scenario("Users").exec(Post.post)
  setUp(
    users.inject(rampUsers(1000) over (10 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

However, I get this error when compiling: value body is not a member of io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value body'?

How do I specify the body of the message that I want to send?

Answer (score 20):

This is old Gatling 1 syntax (Gatling 1 is deprecated and no longer maintained).

Please read the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0/http/http_request.html#request-body).

In you case, you'd get something like:

```
.body(StringBody("""{"id1":"0000000000"}"""))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per current documentation, it is like this:

```
.body(StringBody("""{ "id1":"0000000000" }""")).asJson
```

Also remove extra closing bracket at:

```
.queryParam("""size""", "10"))
```

Place the closing bracket correctly like below:

```
.pause(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, it looks like you closed your `exec` blog a bit too fast, just after `queryParam("""size""", "10")`.

The closing parenthesis should after `.body(...)`, not after `.queryParam(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the method formParam(key: Expression[String], value: Expression[Any])  to post the message to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send request body as follows

```
.body(StringBody("""{
                           "name": "morpheus",
                           "job": "leader"
                       } """)).asJson)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain how it answers the question, so that it is useful to users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`.body(RawFileBody("test-data/your-request-body.json"))`

Here '*test-data*' is present in '*resources*' folder.